# Adding references to current project to CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to compile a string using CodeDom.

```
Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
            };
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = true,
            GenerateExecutable = false
        };

        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

My problem is: In my compiled code I need to use classes from the project I am creating the code in. So I tried to add my current assembly as a reference, however it gives me the following error:

> Metadata file 'Path\to\my\executable\MyProject.exe' could not be
>   opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.'

Anybody knows where my mistake is?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you built your program targeting .NET 4.0 or higher.  So not only can the v3.5 compiler not read the metadata, the final program cannot run either.  Specifying the compiler version is just not useful since it always must match your exe settings anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and I solved this way:

```
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(a => a.Name + ".dll").ToArray());
```

the `+".dll"` worked with me.
if you need to get the full path to the Assembly file you need to load them into a new AppDomain and then get the `.Location` of each one of them.